# prompt for network setup during kickstart installation centos7

Tags: centos, networking, ip, kickstart

I am trying to set the IP manually during a kickstart installation using CentOS 7. During the installation it has to prompt for the network setup.

I tried using the below configuration :

`network --device=enp0s3 --bootproto=static`

But this doesn't prompt for network setup.

I tried `network device=enp0s3 --bootproto=query` and `asknetwork` too, but both are deprecated.

I am aware that we can set it as `network --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.1.120` inside the kickstart file, but I do not want it that way.

Comment: 'asknetwork' is deprecated and will not work on centos7 kickstarts: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/511263

Answer (score 0):

under `network (optional):` at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html

> If you need to manually specify network settings during an
>   otherwise-automated kickstart installation, do not use network.
>   Instead, boot the system with the asknetwork option (refer to Section
>   32.10, “Starting a Kickstart Installation”), which will prompt anaconda to ask you for network settings rather than use the default
>   settings. anaconda will ask this before fetching the kickstart file.